# GridView paging allowed but disabled, possible?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination

For a `GridView`, is there any way I can have `AllowPaging="true"` but have the pagination links disabled (still visible but not clickable)?

(It's for when the user decides to edit the `GridView`. In edit mode, `Labels` inside cells become `TextBoxes`.)

I've tried `Enabled="false"` but this disables everything, including the `TextBoxes`.

I suppose I could handle paging on the server side but I'd rather just disable the pagination links if it's possible.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: why do you want it visible and disabled? any specific reason why you cannot set the pager not visible when the grid switched to EditMode?

Comment: Just so the user knows what page they're on. What you said might be better though, how do I do that?

Comment: not to worry, i followed the solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565992/add-tooltip-to-paging-link-in-asp-net-gridview. i can also use this to make the pager not visible. thanks for your help

Comment: Please post your gridview markup so we can see how the paging is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hide Pager on RowEditing and show it again on Cancel or Update:

```
  void CustomerGridView_RowEditing(Object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    // Hide the pager row.
    CustomerGridView.PagerSettings.Visible = false;
  }

  void CustomerGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.CommandName == "Cancel" || e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
      // Show the pager row.
      CustomerGridView.PagerSettings.Visible = true;
    }
  }
```